# Store captured images in an array?

Tags: uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have looked everywhere trying to find the answer to this question, I have a camera screen where you take a photo and the photo then needs to be stored somewhere which then can be later accessed from a tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing images captured in a `UIImagePickerController` in an `NSArray` is valid.

You can have something like this:

```
/* ViewController.h */
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *photos;

/* ViewController.m */
@synthesize imagePicker = _imagePicker;
@synthesize photos = _photos;

// initialize imagePicker
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
self.imagePicker = imagePicker;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.photos addObject:selectedImage];
}
```

**EDIT:** To view the images from the array in a table view, you can have something like this:

```
// I'm assuming you only have 1 section for the table view

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.photos count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // get / instantiate cell

    // This will use the default imageView in a UITableViewCell.
    cell.imageView.image = [self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: Perfect! and just one more question, what code would you use to display images from the array in a tableview?

Comment: Also would just like to add that when i do reach 15 reputation points i will be voting up your answer!

Comment: @AndrewGierens I updated my answer to include code to display the images in the table view. HTH :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but would you happen to know how to access the array from another UITableView? Would I have to add a property in app delegate? Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean another UITableView in another UIViewController? If you are accessing the second view controller from your first, you can  put a property in the second view controller then pass the array, like `secondViewController.images = self.photos;`.

Comment: I dont understand how to implement this into my code, would you be able to edit the code up the top? Would be much appreciated